# Separate identical field names for filters - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, activeadmin

My active admin project has 2 table fields with identical name(created_at) on 2 separate tables(complaints and sales order) and i must enter 2 filters on a ruby page from the admin folder.
For example :

```
filter :created_at ,label: "Sales Order Created At:"
filter :created_at ,label: "Complaint Created At:"
```

How can i differentiate the two fields?

Comment: This two resources are on the same page?

Comment: Yes. Anyway i fixed the problem. My noob fault it was.